# MongoDB not functioning properly - how to troubleshoot

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-modules

I have installed MongoDB in my Windows 11 through zip file, I also have added the path of the bin folder of the MongoDB file in my environment variables path. But when I am trying to run my code the code executes and could not run anything.

I am adding my code below. I am also adding the image of the cmd; in that you can clearly see that it has executed the code and then does nothing.

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

const connectionURL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';
const databaseName = 'task-manager';

MongoClient.connect(connectionURL, (error,client)=> {
    if(error){
        return console.log('Unable to connect to database',error);
    }
    console.log('Connected Successfully');
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTIsG.jpg)

In the code above one can see that this is very basic code and in the code above I am just trying to print "Connected Successfully" just to make sure that database is connected successfully.

And unfortunately it is not getting printed.

Answer (score 0):

First, `MongoClient` is a class that needs to be instantiated using the `new` keyword. Also, the `MongoClient.connect` function is an async function that returns a promise where you can either use `then/catch` or `async/await`. Using `then` and `catch`, your code should look like this:

```js
const mongodb = require("mongodb");

const connectionURL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';
const dbclient = new mongodb.MongoClient(connectionURL /*insert connection options here*/);

dbclient.connect()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Connected Successfully");
        // Execute logic here after connect
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Unable to connect to database", err);
    });
```

Note that anything that you want to happen after the connection needs to go inside the `then` callback function. I would recommend putting this code in an `async` function and `await`ing the connect function instead, as the code would look cleaner.

Comment: Hi @SwampyX, The code is working fine, Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please help me with this code also, In this code, I am trying to insert some data in my database and I am catching some errors.

Comment: const mongodb = require("mongodb");
const connectionURL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';
const dbclient = new mongodb.MongoClient(connectionURL);

const databaseName = 'task-manager';

dbclient.connect()
    .then(() => {
        //console.log("Connected Successfully");
        // Execute logic here after connect

        const db = client.db(databaseName);
        db.collection('users').insertOne({
         name: 'Keshav Garg',
         age: 24,
        })


    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Unable to connect to database", err);
    });